# Quit the video player screen audio is playing in background in tv os

Tags: ios, objective-c, tvos, avplayerviewcontroller

I am using AVPlayer for playing video url coming from server in TVOS SDK . For getting meta data of video I swipe down in video player screen . In metadata screen there are two buttons Info and Audio out of them click on Info button subtitles. After that clicking on Menu button of Apple TV remote I quit the player screen but audio is still playing in the background .